# How can I get data from array?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart, asynchronous

I need to fetch the list of cat images from the [CAT API](https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search/?apiKey=93c6b2c1-d003-4fbf-8c9c-8413131e9dd3).

This is a data from API

```
[
  {
    "breeds": [],
    "id": "bhf",
    "url": "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/bhf.jpg",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 385
  }
]
```

My code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cats_app_new/constants.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/home-screen';

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Map data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getPics(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        Map data = snapshot.data;
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Text(
            'Failed to get response',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red,
              fontSize: 22.0,
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
              // itemCount: data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        kDefaultPadding / 4,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Image.network(
                          '${data['url'][index]}',
                          // '${data['hits'][index]['largeImageURL']}',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

Future<CatApi> getPics() async {
  String url = 'https://pixabay.com/api/?key=$kApiKey2';
  String url2 = 'https://thecatapi.com/v1/images?api_key=$kApiKey';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url2);
  return CatApi.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
}



class CatApi {
  // List breed;
  String id;
  String url;
  int width;
  int height;

  CatApi(
    this.id,
    this.url,
    this.height,
    this.width,
  );

  factory CatApi.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return CatApi(
      json['id'] as String,
      json['url'] as String,
      json['width'] as int,
      json['height'] as int,
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{${this.url}}';
  }
}
```

In order to display the json object format from json array, I create a separate class CatApi where I describe the parameters of the fields that I intend to display. At the moment I am only using the 'url' field

I can’t understand what I’m doing wrong to display a list of photos

Comment: check ```snapshot.connectionStatus``` and after that decide for ```snapshot.data```

Answer (score 0):

The http response you've provided with the question is a *List of Map* but in the fromJson method in the CatApi class you're treating it as a *Map*

```
factory CatApi.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return CatApi(
      json['id'] as String,
      json['url'] as String,
      json['width'] as int,
      json['height'] as int,
    );
  }
```

Also, in your getPics() method, the url you're using to fetch the response is not the same as the link you've provided in the question. Do both links return the same response?